# Does FaceID improve over time?

Tags: ios, face-id

I switched to iPhone 11 recently and I find FaceID rather disappointing, it often analyzes my face several times before recognizing it and sometimes I have to type my code. I tried to reconfigure it and do it in different situations but it didn't change anything.

Does the technology improve when you use it, with a kind of learning machine? How do I get him to recognize my face better?

Comment: Are you running the most up-to-date version of iOS 13? Check if you have any software updates available by going to Settings app → General → Software Update. If not, make sure you update to the latest available version of iOS and see if that improves face recognition. Also try re-enrolling your face after installing the software update.

Comment: Yes I always install the latest iOS version, I tried to do the FaceID setup several times too

Comment: @Lulucmy Are you sure you're looking into the front camera to unlock it ?

Comment: Yes I'm looking into the notch, I'll try to disable "Require Attention"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As the system is used, it learns about typical variations in a user's
>   appearance, and will adjust its registered face data to match aging,
>   facial hair growth, and other changes using the Neural Engine. The
>   system will recognize a face wearing hats, scarves, glasses, many
>   sunglasses,<sup>[9](https://www.macrumors.com/2017/09/13/how-iphone-x-face-id-works/)</sup> facial hair or makeup.<sup>[10](https://www.macrumors.com/2017/09/14/face-id-works-with-sunglasses-thwarts-thieves/)</sup>

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Face_ID#Technology

Comment: Thanks, but how can it recognize my face better?

Comment: See the comment by Nimesh.. re-enrolling the face could improve a bit. you anyway don't have any machine learnt data to lose IF you are not using it for months.